# How do I retrieve a discord user's status

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command(aliases=["stat"])
async def status(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    try:
        em = discord.Embed(description=discord.Status) 
        em.set_author(name="User Status", icon_url=user.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERROR]: {Fore.BLUE}{e}" + Fore.RESET)`#Printing Error
```

discord.Status Discord documentation says this is how to retrieve a user status but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

[discord.Status](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Status) is the class that represents a user's status. Your `user` variable is of the type [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member), which has a [status field](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.status).

So you can access it by using `user.status`. The complete code would then look like this:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["stat"])
async def status(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    try:
        em = discord.Embed(description=user.status) 
        em.set_author(name="User Status", icon_url=user.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERROR]: {Fore.BLUE}{e}" + Fore.RESET)`#Printing Error
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!